# Does Windows 8 overwrite Win7 on Partition?

Tags: partitioning, windows-8, operating-systems

On my HP laptop, I have two partitions: a c-drive and a d-drive. Windows 7 was installed on the d-drive. I downloaded Windows 8 using Windows Upgrade Assistant and installed.

My question is on which drive did Windows 8 install?

Comment: Are you currently using that Windows 8? If so, press Win+R and type %windir% hit enter and you will see in which partition it is located Windows directory.

Comment: Thank you. It was in the c-dive. But that folder was only 1gb big. That can't be all?

Comment: If you upgraded from Windows 7, then by definition, Windows 8 is installed on the same partition your old OS, Windows 7 was installed. If you wanted it to be dual boot on a separate partition, then you need to install a new copy, and do that by using a CD boot disk, and select the correct partition to install it on

Comment: But how come I come to c:\ when I enter %windir% in run?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know exactly what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to computer view and you will see the Windows logo icon indicating where the system was installed. See [this](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/windows-8-file-explorer-features/).

[image]