# Upgrade to Win8 left my Win7 files untouched, How to replace/delete?

Tags: partitioning, windows-8, windows-7-backup

According to [this link,](https://superuser.com/questions/498902/does-windows-8-overwrite-win7-on-partition/498917#498917) which I posted, my Windows 8 didn't overwrite my windows 7 partition. So  now, my recovery partition of 26gb is useless.

Is there any chance I Could remove that partition and replace it with Windows 8? Or if not: How do I remove that partition and all files? And is it same to remove it? Or is windows 8 using windows 7 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could boot up a Linux LiveCD like (www.ubuntu.com) and delete the recovery partition. If you restored using the manufacture's disaster recovery, it will wipe everything, including your Windows 8 installation. You will use a utility called GPARTED.

When you boot back into Windows 8, you can expand your hard drive volume to consume the remaining 26GB of unpartitioned space. Right click on computer and select manage or go to Disk Management in the Administrative Tools under Control Panel. You should see the empty space. Right click on your Windows installation partition and select Expand.